# Is it possible to use Cordova Plugin in NativeScript?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plugins, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am developing a NativeScript Project and want to implement the functionality of the Custom Cordova Plugin. Is there any possibilities that I can reuse my Custom Cordova Plugin into the NativeScript Project.

I have tried adding the Cordova Plugin and was successful in doing so but when I implemented its functionalities I got the error that module was missing. Any Help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They [announced](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-use-any-cordova-plugin-with-nativescript) last week that they were implementing a [plugin](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cordova-imagepicker-showcase/tree/master/cordova-nativescript-plugin) to add support

Right now it only works for Android, but they say it will work on iOS too.

here is the [Demo app](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cordova-imagepicker-showcase/tree/master/demo), you can try it like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cordova-imagepicker-showcase
cd nativescript-cordova-imagepicker-showcase
cd demo
tns run android
```